# INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE using pg-promise helpers for multi row insert/update

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, pg-promise

I am trying to insert multiple rows to pgsql database using pg-promise. In my case, few records, which I am trying to insert, may exist already in the table. In such case, I need to update them. By going through the [pg-promise official documentaion](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/index.html), I found multiple rows can either be inserted or updated using [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html). Is there any way to do like below but for multiple inserts/updates?

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_list) 
VALUES(value_list)
ON CONFLICT target action;
```

Comment: Yes, just create the insert-values query using helpers, then tack on the `ON CONFLICT …` as a string.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, pretty much. I added my answer anyhow, might help a bit more :)

Comment: @vitaly-t Yeah, but I didn't know from the top of my head how it would look exactly, and I didn't know about `assignColumns`!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create your static variables somewhere:

```js
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'], 
                                      {table: 'my-table'});

// let's assume columns 'first' and 'second' produce conflict when exist:
const onConflict = ' ON CONFLICT(first, second) DO UPDATE SET ' +
    cs.assignColumns({from: 'EXCLUDED', skip: ['first', 'second']});
```

- See [ColumnSet](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) and [assignColumns](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html#assignColumns).

In the example below we assume your `data` is an array of valid objects:

```js
const upsert = pgp.helpers.insert(data, cs) + onConflict; // generates upsert

await db.none(upsert); // executes the query:
```

---

#### Extras

If you want all SQL generated in upper case rather than low case, you can set option `capSQL`:

```js
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({
  capSQL: true
});
```

And the best way to see what's generated and executed is with the help of [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor).

Comment: What if your update is dependent on current value?
Like first = my-table.first + EXCLUDED.first
Should you just add it part of the onConflict query or can you do something with assignColumns?

Comment: @MariusMircea You would just have to append that manually, `assignColumns` is there only to simplify regular assignment, because that covers 99% of all practical cases. And what you are asking is fairly unique.

Comment: Works perfectly! For anyone like me who was confused at the use of 'EXCLUDED', it is a postgres syntax for accessing the row that we were unsuccessful in inserting https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: Is there any method to have the count of rows updated and the count of rows created returned? I see using `db.result()` we receive `rowCount` however nothing to specify columns which hit the conflict.

Comment: thanks mate this is gold! I have never worked with pg but this is awesome!